# Found used undeclared dependencies junit 4.13 when I use junit 5

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

I'm moving from junit 4 to junit 5. I ran into a problem when analyzing dependencies.
when I run mvn dependency:analyze, an error occurs:

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO] Add the following to your pom to correct the missing dependencies: 
[INFO] 
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <execution>
            <id>analyze</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>analyze-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <ignoredDependencies>
              <ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies>junit:junit:jar:4.13</ignoredUsedUndeclaredDependencies>
            </ignoredDependencies>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Please help us eliminate this error

Answer (score 3):

Used undeclared dependencies are those which are required, but have not been explicitly declared as dependencies in your project. It is a good style to directly declare the used dependencies and not rely on transitive dependencies. This is not a problem, it's just not nice.

You should investigate, which parts of your code use JUnit 4 code. To make the search easier, you could temporarily exclude it:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

As you did not show any versions in your example, I cannot tell where the transitive dependency comes from, thus where to put the exclusion.

Comment: this dependence is used in the org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
I used the command  mvn dependency:tree
and I got the following dependency tree

\- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
    \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test

Comment: The purpose of the JUnit vintage engine is to support older JUnit 3/4 test.
- If you don't have them, get rid of the vintage engine.
- If you have them, declare a dependency to JUnit 4.13 as described in your error message.

Comment: I added the junit 4.13 dependency - the error is not reproduced. I thought I should add a vintage dependency and remove junit 4.13. Thank you for your answer.